# SVPWM Dwell time calculation and switching vector

Tags: microcontroller, simulation, matlab

I have modeled a SVPWM for a two-level, three-phase inverter. The modulation index for svpwm is selected as MI = 3*Vref/2*Vdc, the dwell time is selected based on sector and alpha (angle in each sector), the Vref is selected as 300, and Vdc is given as 500 volts, so based on the above formula, the MI index is 0.9. so the maximum value for T1,T2 is 0.9, where T0 is around -1. for calculating active voltage vector i used sector formula to derive S1,S3,S5 such as

```
   if(n==1)
    s1=t1+t2+tzero/2;
    s3=t2+tzero/2;
    s5=tzero/2;
   end
   if(n==2)
    s1=t1+tzero/2;
    s3=t1+t2+tzero/2;
    s5=tzero/2;
   end
   if(n==3)
    s1=tzero/2;
    s3=t1+t2+tzero/2;
    s5=t2+tzero/2;
   end
   if(n==4)
    s1=tzero/2;
    s3=t1+tzero/2;
    s5=t1+t2+tzero/2;
   end
   if(n==5)
    s1=t2+tzero/2;
    s3=tzero/2;
    s5=t1+t2+tzero/2;
   end
   if(n==6)
    s1=t1+t2+tzero/2;
    s3=tzero/2;
    s5=t1+tzero/2;
   end
```

However, the amplitude for s1,s3,s5 is 0.52 which is incorrect because the modulation index is 0.9, so the maximum value for active voltage s1,s3,s5 should be 0.9. the picture is attached for better understanding. Can anyone tell me what the actual problem is? [s1,s3,s5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUm3J.jpg)
[T1,T2,Tzero](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShqCu.jpg)